# How to apply SUBTOTAL count distinct in Libre Office Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I've applied `=SUBTOTAL(3, RANGE:RANGE)` but I need to count only the unique values.

is there any way like this `=SUBTOTAL('function-distinct', RANGE:RANGE)`

How to apply SUBTOTAL count distinct in Libre Office Calc ?

Comment: Im not positive as i dont have it installed anymore but does =COUNTIF(B2:B10,B2:B10) -1 work?

Comment: Not working, it's returning **`#VALUE!`**